# Texstudio has an odd way to display the text I am editing

Tags: texstudio, editors

[image]

Never had this problem before, but I installed Texstudio on a new computer and this is what is happening. Not only is the paragraph on which I am working shown in a different facon, but also when I start typing, it is not where the cursor is.

Please help, I can not work like this!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'd look for some invisible character that could trigger this strange behavior. What if you copy the offending part to another file?

Comment: Thank you, but it does the same thing when I open another file.